# Inline JavaScript seems to load randomly, if at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

*First off, I'd like to say that I'm sorry if this is an easy question. I'm fairly new to the HTML/CSS scene, and haven't even arrived at the Javascript one yet.*

Here's my problem. I have a website I'm trying to build for my uncle, which you can see [here](http://burntonionbeta.altervista.org/). (it's still deep in pre-alpha stage, so the links don't work). It works fine as a local file, but as soon as I host it, my 'sticky' header starts to stick too soon, if at all. Reloading the page works about 1 time in 10.

I may or may not have isolated the cause of the problem: my placeholder. My sticky code itself works fine most of the time, except for one thing: as the sticky bar docks, it becomes fixed and the text jumps up 90-odd pixels. To combat this, I added lines **6** and **7** to my code below:

```
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;
function onScroll(e) {
window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') :
  sticky.classList.remove('fixed');               
window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? jQuery('.content').css("paddingTop", "88.8125px"):
  jQuery('.content').css("paddingTop", "0px");
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

It basically sticks a placeholder in there to stop that jump. It works fine, except now it's broken my code. I have experimented a bit and discovered that the placeholder seems to load randomly, and the header just goes weird. That's the best I can do.

It seems to be the placeholder code breaking it, as [without the code](http://burntonionbeta.altervista.org/testingpage.html) it seems to work fine, perhaps after a couple of reloads. However, I am completely stumped. Has anyone got any idea how to fix it?

(Tested in Chrome 64 bit and 32 bit, as well as Chrome for Android, although that's glitchy on another level. Works fine as a local page, but not when hosted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the these code is executed too early that the image is not loaded yet, you can use chrome dev tool to add a pause to break to `var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;`.

Then you can see 2 cases: `22` or `642`

You can further inspect that the image, which should be the banner, is not completed when `22` condition is met, and if you use `document.querySelector('.splash img')` to get it and check its height, you'll see `0`. While in the `642` case, you'll get `500`.

The difference may be sometimes the image come from cache, sometimes it load from internet, so it may or may not able to decide the height when your script is executed.

So we have to make sure the `image` which is in the `.splash` is already loaded:

```
<script>

// Wrap the logic to a function for call.
var stickFunction = function() {
    var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
    var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;

    function onScroll(e) {
      window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') :
                                      sticky.classList.remove('fixed');

      window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? jQuery('.content').css("paddingTop", "88.8125px"):
                                      jQuery('.content').css("paddingTop", "0px");
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
}

// Get the image element
var splashImage = document.querySelector('.splash img');

// Check if image is complete or not.
if (splashImage.complete) { // If completed, do the logic.
    stickFunction();
} else { // If not, tell the image to call the function for you when it is loaded.
    splashImage.onload = stickFunction;
}


</script>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Never even occurred to me that load times could be a problem. Your solution works perfectly. You have furthered my knowledge of both JS and Chrome's dev tools, which I didn't really know existed, and for that I take my hat off to you. Have a hi-five!